energy efficiency and time for a SIMD broadcast systolic data flow deep neural network
Im trying to understand why memfetch is multiplied by km(L+1)/8 instead of NMACS which is 8 and also what is meant by systolic clk increment
Consider a fully connected layer. Let
• X ∈ RK×L real 32bit floating point matrix as input matrix
• W ∈ RL×M real 32bit floating point matrix as weight matrix
• H ∈ RK×M real 32bit floating point matrix as output matrix
• K = 4 (batch size), L = 24 (input size), M = 8 (output size)
the *3 in memfetch is because we do 64 bit memfetch so 6 *2 inputs 4 weights) 32 bits will be fetch in 3 64 bits


